# How to plot a sum with Maple?

Tags: sum, maple

I would like to draw with Maple the following expression :

```
> I_n:=Sum((H_(k+1)H_(n-k+1))/k+2,k=0..n);
```

witch

```
>  H_n:=sum(1/k,k=1..n);
```

My work:

```
>f:=n->sum(1/k,k=1..n); 
I_n:=sum(f(j+1)*f(n-j+1)/(j+2), j = 0 .. n);
```

But I do not see how I can draw this.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plot(I_n, n= 0..20);` 
or change 20 to any other upper limit.

Comment: After reading Acer's answer, I realized that you used both lowercase `sum` and capitalized `Sum`. My answer only applies if you use lowercase `sum` consistently.

Comment: If `sum` is used in both places then `plot(I_n, n= 0..20)` will compute the symbolic `sum` result at non-integer values. Since the call to `sum` for defining `I_n` results in an expression with `n` outside any unevaluated `sum` then float values for `n` used by `plot` will generate values and a curve that are spurious IF only integer values of `n` were intended (as seems a reasoable guess).

Answer (score 1):

It makes a big difference to the result if you distinguish whether `n` is allowed to take on non-integer values (eg. n=10.23 etc).

You originally wrote `Sum` for defining `I_n`, but then your code fragment had lowercase `sum`. You should be careful about which you try and use because it will affect what happens when `plot` tries to use non-integer values of `n`. (Using `Sum` without any rounding call on `n` will also risk generating an empty plot since `evalf/Sum` will baulk at the non-float values and you can get an empty plot by accident.)

Compare all these, and especially note the `n` that appear outside the summation (as a partial result) when using `sum` to define `I_n`.

It's up to you to figure out whether you wanted `n` to be purely integer-valued, and then choose the plotting method accordingly.

```
f:=n->sum(1/k,k=1..n):

I_n:=Sum(f(j+1)*f(n-j+1)/(j+2), j = 0 .. n);

sum(f(j+1)*f(n-j+1)/(j+2), j = 0 .. n); # Note the `n` outisde the sum.

value(I_n); # As if I_n:=sum(...) had been used. Note the `n` outside the sum.

plot(value(I_n), n= 0..20); # also what you'd get if you plotted I_N:=sum(...)

plot(subs(n=floor(n),I_n), n=0..20); # Step function. Could also try with round().

plot(I_n, n=0..20); # Empty plot since I_n=Sum(...) used without rounding `n`.

plots:-pointplot([seq([n,I_n],n=0..20)]); # use style=line option to join the points
```

My main point is that the result from executing `sum(f(j+1)*f(n-j+1)/(j+2), j = 0 .. n)` may well be not something that you intended to plot in the case that `n` is not an integer. And if so then you should account for that when plotting it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, it is very interesting. So if I understood correctly I have to use -pointplot([seq([n,I_n],n=0..20)]) to plot the sum with n purely integer ?

Comment: If you only want integer values of n to be used in generating the plot then one way to achieve that is to create a listlist (as I did with that pointplot example) or a mx2 Matrix of n and I_n values. You could then use that with either the plots:-plot or the plot command, I think, and control the appearance using either the style=point or style=line options within those commands.